# How do I get domain's nameservers from the "source"?

Tags: dns, whois

When I run `whois google.com`, it shows following name servers:

```
Name Server: ns2.google.com
Name Server: ns4.google.com
Name Server: ns3.google.com
Name Server: ns1.google.com
```

So my question is, where is the source of this data? Can I make some kind of request (http/tcp/udp etc.) to get it directly from the "source", without doing whois command?

Comment: On the SuperUser site: [Where does the whois command get its information from?](https://superuser.com/questions/1155349/where-does-the-whois-command-get-its-information-from)

Comment: @Flux Question: Does it mean when I make a request to an unknown subdomain, for example `curl unique123.google.com`, my computer or some recursive dns resolver down the line first makes "whois" request to get nameservers for google.com?

Comment: nope. DNS servers all use yet-an-other static list of servers: the IP addresses of the 13 root DNS servers (with ip anycast kind of load balancing there are much more than 13 actually) from which to start the cascading requests. https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers . Looks again like an https://xyproblem.info/ . WHOIS is completely separate from DNS, even if what is available in WHOIS gives information on what should be available in DNS.

Comment: Would your question actually be "How do I find the list of name servers for a given domain"?

Comment: @A.B Yes, it would! But I want to understand where the data is coming from, not simply a linux command that I can run and get the result

Comment: @userQWERTY beware of "Requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications). " . DNS is not specific to Unix/Linux. So if your question is purely about DNS, it might be off-topic. cf: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You can start there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System or https://whois.icann.org/en/dns-and-whois-how-it-works